# Bonferroni-Dunn Critical differences

Tags: python, bonferroni, dunn-test

I was reading about visualizing post-hoc tests and I happened to come across a Python package called [Orange](https://medium.com/@catur.supriyanto/how-to-visualize-the-nemenyi-and-bonferroni-dunn-diagrams-in-python-aa6a311f1cee).
Looking into the package, the function used for calculating the CD value seems to be deprecated, but I came across [this copy of it](https://github.com/pedrormjunior/ossvm-results/blob/master/critical_distance.py). My question is about the values that are hard-coded, as shown below. I would really appreciate an explanation for these values to figure out how they are calculated:

```
d = {("bonferroni-dunn", 0.05): [0, 0, 1.960, 2.241, 2.394, 2.498, 2.576,
                                       2.638, 2.690, 2.724, 2.773],
     ("bonferroni-dunn", 0.1): [0, 0, 1.645, 1.960, 2.128, 2.241, 2.326,
                                      2.394, 2.450, 2.498, 2.539]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: compute $0.5/\Phi(-d)$ where $\Phi$ is the standard Normal distribution function.  You will discover that the "2.724" value is erroneous: it should be 2.734.